# OpenCV StereoBM - Can it run on openCL?

Tags: opencv, opencl

I am trying to figure out whether `StereoBM` is implemented for `OpenCL` in `OpenCV`.

The docs are unclear, as for `OpenCV 2.4`, a list of functions implemented with `OCL` was [provided](https://docs.huihoo.com/opencv/2.4-documentation/modules/ocl/doc/operations_on_matrices.html).

However, for `OpenCV3.4`, no such information seems present.

`StereoBM` is implemented [for CUDA](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d34/group__cudaarithm__elem.html#ga2cd14a684ea70c6ab2a63ee90ffe6201).

However, is it implemented for `openCL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereobm.cpp

It contains mentions of OpenCL kernels. There appears to be an OpenCL kernel for the block matching part too.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/opencl/stereobm.cl

So the answer is yes, it does use OpenCL.